# Script returning limited amount of records as compare to Query

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I tried to convert an SQL query into Gosu Script ( Guidewire). My script is working only for limited number of records

This is the SQL query

```
select  PolicyNumber,* from pc_policyperiod 
where ID in ( Select ownerID from pc_PRActiveWorkflow 
where ForeignEntityID in (Select id from pc_workflow where State=3))
```

This is my script

```
var workFlowIDQuery = Query.make(Workflow).compare(Workflow#State,Relop.Equals,WorkflowState.TC_COMPLETED).select({QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(entity.Workflow#ID))}).transformQueryRow(\row ->row.getColumn(0)).toTypedArray()

var prActiveWorkFlowQuery = Query.make(PRActiveWorkflow).compareIn(PRActiveWorkflow#ForeignEntity, workFlowIDQuery).select({QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(entity.PRActiveWorkflow#Owner))}).transformQueryRow(\row -> row.getColumn(0)).toTypedArray()

var periodQuery = Query.make(PolicyPeriod).compareIn(PolicyPeriod#ID,prActiveWorkFlowQuery).select()

for(period in periodQuery){
  print(period.policynmber)
}
```

Can anyone find a cause; why the script results in limited records or suggest improvements?

Comment: generally a gosu query won't return a row that is retired while an SQL query will.  So you might want to check that in your SQL query (retired should be null).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a single Gosu Query to select policyPeriod and join 3 entities with a foreign key to other entity.

I am note sure if the PolicyPeriod ID is same as the PRActiveWorkflow ID. Can you elaborate the relation between PolicyPeriod and PRActiveWorkflow entity ?

Answer (score 0):

A Gosu query does not return retired records whereas a SQL query returns retired records unless you have an explicit condition to exclude retired records.

You may want to check by excluding retired records in your SQL query.

**Note:** Any non-zero value in the Retired column indicates that the record is retired.